# Error converting Java interface to Json schema

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I am trying to convert a java interface to json schema but it is giving NullPointerException

```
public interface Contributors {

public List<Contributor> contributors();

public interface Contributor {

    public String name();

    public String contributorUrl();

    public List<String> roles();

}

}
```

Edit 2:
I am getting the following output:

```
{"type":"object","$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"}
```

Edit 3:

Following is the code of SchemaGeneratorTest

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.github.reinert.jjschema.exception.TypeException;
import com.github.reinert.jjschema.v1.JsonSchemaFactory;
import com.github.reinert.jjschema.v1.JsonSchemaV4Factory;

public class SchemaGeneratorTest {
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    public static final String JSON_$SCHEMA_DRAFT4_VALUE = "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#";
    public static final String JSON_$SCHEMA_ELEMENT = "$schema";

    static {
        // required for pretty printing
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, TypeException {

        JsonSchemaFactory schemaFactory = new JsonSchemaV4Factory();
        schemaFactory.setAutoPutDollarSchema(true);
        JsonNode productSchema = schemaFactory.createSchema(Contributors.class);
        System.out.println(productSchema);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Did you write SchemaGeneratorTest? If so, please post that code.

Comment: Did you try to debug it? A NullPointerException is easy to find.

Comment: @Nulano Updated.

Comment: Are you using an up to date version of the library? This stack trace seems impossible from the GitHub you provided.

Comment: Btw, even if your interface were an abstract class, you shouldn't get any output, since the library only processes methods which are prefixed with "get" or "is". (At least according to the github src).

Comment: @Nulano Yes actually i was using version-0.6 previously. After using 1.2 also it is not able to parse the interface. Any solution to this issue?

Comment: @ArchitMaheshwari Am I right to assume you have a different stack trace now? If so, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Nulano Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are using only reports fields and getters in your schema. Rename your methods to begin with `get`:

```
public interface Contributors {
    public List<Contributor> getContributors();
}

public interface Contributor {
    public String getName();
    public String getContributorUrl();
    public List<String> getRoles();
}
```

EDIT: If you can't modify the interfaces, you can use this code to corrupt the "get" string and get it to print all methods anyway. Please don't use it in real production code, as you will cause yourself a lot of trouble.

```
public class Test {

    private static boolean isCorrupted() {
        return "haha".startsWith("get");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String get = "get";
        Field value = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
        value.setAccessible(true);
        value.set(get, new char[]{});
        System.out.println(isCorrupted()); // prints true
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @nulano Unfortunately i can't touch the interface contract. Any other way to do it without changing the contract?

Comment: @ArchitMaheshwari Unfortunetaly, there is no way to do this without modifying `JsonSchemaGenerator`. You could try opening a feature request issue on github (Something along the lines of - "Add option to consider all methods as getters"). This is a good example of why getters should always be prefixed with `get` or `is`. _Actually, if you really want to, you could probably modify it with reflection, but I think that is outside of the scope of this SO question._

Comment: Yes it seems it isn't supported yet. Could you provide any pointers to convert it by reflection so that the following library can be used for my purpose. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of finding the "get" string that is referenced in isGetter ( https://github.com/reinert/JJSchema/blob/095b6d6a11f4375a4a2d37205dfa5e95fed8c259/src/main/java/com/github/reinert/jjschema/JsonSchemaGenerator.java#L616 ), ("get".intern(), or just "get" should get you that). Then you would modify it's internal memory (the `char[] value` field) to make it an empty string.

Comment: @ArchitMaheshwari I added an example.